# Run Kubernetes on EC2

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, coreos, kubernetes

I am trying to run kubernetes on EC2 and I used CoreOs alpha channel ami.I configured Kubectl ssh tunnel for the communication between Kubectl client and Kubernetes API.

But when I try **kubectl api-versions** command, I am getting following error.

**Couldn't get available api versions from server: Get http://MyIP:8080/api: dial tcp MyIP:8080: connection refused**

MyIP - this has set accordingly.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] or [sf]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason for this issue was that I haven't set the kubernetes_master environment variable properly. As there is a ssh tunnel between the kubectl client and API, kubernetes master environment variable should be set to localhost.